# Removing initial 0 records in SQL Server

Tags: sql-server

I got a question in an interview. Looking for a solution

Question: I have a table in SQL Server which has 4 columns in which the first few records are 0 and the output they required is removing first 0 records but not those 0 records who come after some natural numbers. The initial 0 records can be dynamic .I'm mentioning the input table and output table.

Table:

```
A   B   C   D
-------------
0   0   0   0
0   0   0   0
0   0   0   0
0   0   0   0
0   0   0   0
0   0   0   0
1   2   3   4
0   0   0   0
5   6   7   8
2   3   5   6
1   3   4   5
```

The output table:

```
A   B   C   D
-------------
1   2   3   4
0   0   0   0
5   6   7   8
2   3   5   6
1   3   4   5
```

Can anyone help me get this output?

Thanks in advance

Comment: There is no T-SQL solution to this problem because a table is an unordered set of rows and the requirements say "first" which has no meaning unless the set is ordered. You would need an incremental value on which to order by to achieve the desired results. Hopefully, that is the answer to the interviewer was looking for.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I hope you want to fetch where first records from all columns in Non zero.
There is a trick. NOT recommended for production.

**EDIT(From Dan)** The solution will not work if the table has a clustered index and may not work if the database has multiple files.

```
CREATE TABLE test23
(
     A INT 
    ,B INT 
    ,C INT 
    ,D INT
)
GO

INSERT INTO test23 VALUES
(0,0,0,0),
(0,0,0,0),
(0,0,0,0),
(0,0,0,0),
(0,0,0,0),
(0,0,0,0),
(1,2,3,4),
(0,0,0,0),
(5,6,7,8),
(2,3,5,6),
(1,3,4,5)
GO

SELECT * 
       FROM
test23 
        WHERE  %%PhysLoc%% >= 
        (
            SELECT MIN(%%PhysLoc%%) FROM test23 WHERE a+b+c+d > 0
        )
```

**OUTPUT**

```
A           B           C           D
----------- ----------- ----------- -----------
1           2           3           4
0           0           0           0
5           6           7           8
2           3           5           6
1           3           4           5

(5 rows affected)
```

Comment: Add to your answer why this trick should not be used in production. In short, it will not work if the table has a clustered index and may not work if the database has multiple files.

Comment: Hi Dan, Added. Thank you.

Comment: Thanks Dan. Can you help me out what if I need to do same thing in Oracle

Answer (score 0):

Suppose your table name is **tableA** and column name is **A, B, C,D**
so the query would be

```
SELECT DISTINCT A,B, C,D FROM tableA
```

Please, read basic SQL server through W3School that would be helpful.